# seems like laravel not sending email from sendgrid smtp

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, sendgrid

I am using `laravel` mail using this configuration,

```
return array(
  'driver' => 'mail',
  'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  'from' => array('address' => 'info@from.com', 'name' => 'test'),
  'encryption' => 'tls',
  'username' => 'sendgrid_username',
  'password' => 'sendgrid_password
);
```

mail is receiving but issue is `gmail` sending it to spam, see [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0465uly26e)

`Gmail` says `this message was not encrypted` and `Gmail couldn't verify that test.com actually sent this message`.
Also i checked my `sendgrid` account, but no email used.

Comment: Does `from.com` have an `spf` record setup?

Comment: sorry i am not sure what is `spf` @RiggsFolly how can i check this?

Comment: You will have to look at your sites DNS you should find it as a TXT record in there, if one exists

Comment: @RiggsFolly i changed that one email id which configured in my host, and error `Gmail couldn't verify that test.com actually sent this message` no more, but still showing `this message was not encrypted`. what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the whitelabel configuration process so that SendGrid is authorized to send email on behalf of the domain that you want to use. This involves making sure you have DNS entries in place that will allow SPF and DKIM checks to pass. You can find out more via the [SendGrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Deliver/Delivery_Introduction/all_you_need_to_know_about_whitelabeling.html).